# Scala 2.11.7 and standard github eg throws error

Tags: java, scala

Running scala 2.11.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 with Java 1.8.0_45

Using the scala shell and loading a standard github example below throws an error "illegal start of definition" on the first executable line of the code, ie package org.apache.spark.examples ...
saying object apache is not a member of package org.

Which to me is wholly unexpected from a standard command: code below:

```
// scalastyle:off println

package org.apache.spark.examples

import scala.math.random

import org.apache.spark._ import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

object LocalPi {   def main(args: Array[String]) {
 var count = 0
 for (i <- 1 to 100000) {
   val x = random * 2 - 1
   val y = random * 2 - 1
   if (x*x + y*y < 1) count += 1
 }
 println("Pi is roughly " + 4 * count / 100000.0)   } } // scalastyle:on println
```

Comment: Have you included the org.apache libraries in your classpath?

Comment: @Bob Dalgleish  No, but two questions: a) how do i infer the jar file name from the package statement ( no tutorial i have seen mentions this ) ... though one does mention the existence of classpaths )   and b) Is there a way to specify a dozen or so jar files at the command line by invoking a file which contains a list of the required jar files?

Comment: Using package clause in REPL will give illegal start error unless you `:pa -raw`. Not clear what you've tried here.